# Cross Process Event - Release all waiters reliably

Tags: c#, .net, windows, multithreading

I have created a cross process event via ManualResetEvent. When this event does occur potentially n threads in n different processes should be unblocked and start running to fetch the new data. The problem is that it seems that ManualResetEvent.Set followed by an immediate Reset does not cause all waiting threads to wake up. The docs are pretty vague there

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682396(v=vs.85).aspx

> When the state of a manual-reset event object is signaled, it remains
>   signaled until it is explicitly reset to nonsignaled by the ResetEvent
>   function. Any number of waiting threads, or threads that subsequently
>   begin wait operations for the specified event object, can be released
>   while the object's state is signaled.

There is a method called [PulseEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which seems to do exactly what I need but unfortunately it is also flawed.

> A thread waiting on a synchronization object can be momentarily
>   removed from the wait state by a kernel-mode APC, and then returned to
>   the wait state after the APC is complete. If the call to PulseEvent
>   occurs during the time when the thread has been removed from the wait
>   state, the thread will not be released because PulseEvent releases
>   only those threads that are waiting at the moment it is called.
>   Therefore, PulseEvent is unreliable and should not be used by new
>   applications. Instead, use condition variables.

Now MS does recommend to use condition variables.

> Condition variables are synchronization primitives that enable threads
>   to wait until a particular condition occurs. Condition variables are
>   user-mode objects that **cannot be shared across processes**.

Following the docs I seem to have run out of luck to do it reliably. Is there an easy way to accomplish the same thing without the stated limitations with one ManualResetEvent or do I need to create for each listener process a response event to get an ACK for each subscribed caller? In that case I would need a small shared memory to register the pids of the subscribed processes but that seems to bring in its own set of problems. What does happen when one process crashes or does not respond? ....

To give some context. I have new state to publish which all other processes should read from a shared memory location. It is ok to miss one update when several updates occur at once but the process must read at least the last up to date value. I could poll with a timeout but that seems not like a correct solution.

Currently I am down to

```
ChangeEvent = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset, counterName + "_Event");

ChangeEvent.Set();
Thread.Sleep(1); // increase odds to release all waiters
ChangeEvent.Reset();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One general purpose option for handling the case where producers must wake all consumers and the number of consumers is evolving is to use a moving fence approach.  This option requires a shared memory IPC region too.  The method does sometimes result in consumers being woken when no work is present, especially if lots of processes need scheduling and load is high, but they will always wake except on hopelessly overloaded machines.

Create several manual reset events and have the producers maintain a counter to the next event that will be set.  All Events are left set, except the NextToFire event.  Consumer processes wait on the NextToFire event.  When the producer wishes to wake all consumers it resets the Next+1 event and sets the current event.  All consumers will eventually be scheduled and then wait on the new NextToFire event. The effect is that only the producer uses ResetEvent, but consumers always know which event will be next to wake them.

All Users Init:  (pseudo code is C/C++, not C#)

```
// Create Shared Memory and initialise NextToFire;
pSharedMemory = MapMySharedMemory();
if (First to create memory) pSharedMemory->NextToFire = 0;

HANDLE Array[4];
Array[0] = CreateEvent(NULL, 1, 0, "Event1");
Array[1] = CreateEvent(NULL, 1, 0, "Event2");
Array[2] = CreateEvent(NULL, 1, 0, "Event3");
Array[3] = CreateEvent(NULL, 1, 0, "Event4");
```

Producer to Wake all

```
long CurrentNdx = pSharedMemory->NextToFire;
long NextNdx = (CurrentNdx+1) & 3;

// Reset next event so consumers block
ResetEvent(Array[NextNdx]);

// Flag to consumers new value
long Actual = InterlockedIncrement(&pSharedMemory->NextToFire) & 3;

// Next line needed if multiple producers active.
// Not a perfect solution
if (Actual != NextNdx) ResetEvent(Actual);

// Now wake them all up
SetEvent(CurrentNdx);
```

Consumers wait logic

```
long CurrentNdx = (pSharedMemory->NextToFire) & 3;
WaitForSingleObject(Array[CurrentNdx],  Timeout);
```

Comment: This is a very good solution which solves all race conditions I could come up with. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since .NET 4.0, you could use MemoryMappedFile to sync process memory. In this case, write counter to MemoryMappedFile and decrement it from worker processes. If the counter equals to zero, then main process allowed to reset event. Here is the sample code.

Main Process

```
//number of WorkerProcess
int numWorkerProcess = 5;

//Create MemroyMappedFile object and accessor. 4 means int size.
MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew("test_mmf", 4);
MemoryMappedViewAccessor accessor = mmf.CreateViewAccessor();

EventWaitHandle ChangeEvent = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset, counterName + "_Event");

//write counter to MemoryMappedFile
accessor.Write(0, numWorkerProcess);

//.....

ChangeEvent.Set();

//spin wait until all workerProcesses decreament counter
SpinWait.SpinUntil(() => {

    int numLeft = accessor.ReadInt32(0);
    return (numLeft == 0);
});


ChangeEvent.Reset();
```

WorkerProcess

```
//Create existed MemoryMappedfile object which created by main process.
MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting("test_mmf");
MemoryMappedViewAccessor accessor = mmf.CreateViewAccessor();

//This mutex object is used for decreament counter.
Mutex mutex = new Mutex(false, "test_mutex");
EventWaitHandle ChangeEvent = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset, "start_Event");

//....

ChangeEvent.WaitOne();

//some job...

//decrement counter with mutex lock. 
mutex.WaitOne();
int count = accessor.ReadInt32(0);
--count;
accessor.Write(0, count);
mutex.ReleaseMutex();
/////////////////////////////////////
```

If environment is less than .NET 4.0,  you could realize by using CreateFileMapping function from win32 API.

Comment: That does work but is very fragile. When a process is killed or it does hang it will never decrement the global counter and you will wait forever. If you use a timeout then it can (will) happen that a process decrements the counter just after you have given up. This will in decrement the "full" counter wrongly. How do you determine the number of subscribers and how do you handle the issue if a registered process has silently exited? In that case you need to adjust the subscriber count based on guessing. There are way too many race conditions with this solution.

Comment: @Alois Kraus Yes you're right. It not considering about accident in worker process. But I don't know why your system cannot determine the number of worker process. Because in most case there is controller process which create worker process and manage them. So, these controller process must know the number of worker process and each condition (include errors). In any case, I think the best solution is to prepare event for each worker process, and communicate with controller process.

Comment: It is not so easy since I do not know the number of subscribers and there is no controler. Even if I would know it would be wrong since a subscriber can unsubscribe at any time. This is another race condition that a subscriber does unsubscribe while you are delivering an event based on the old subscription count.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote: “PulseEvent which seems to do exactly what I need but unfortunately it is also flawed”. This is true that PulseEvent is flawed, but I cannot agree that manual-reset event is flawed. It is very reliable. There are just cases when you can use manual-reset events, and there are cases where you cannot use them. It is not one-fits-for-all. There are lots of other tools, like auto-reset events, pipes, etc.

The best way to just notify a thread, if you need to notify it periodically, but don't need to send data across processes, is an auto-reset event. You just need own event for each thread. So, you have as many events as there are threads.

If you need to just send data to processes, it’s better to use named pipes.  Unlike auto-reset events, you don't need own pipe for each of the processes. Each named pipe has a server and one or more clients. When there are many clients, many instances of the same named pipes are automatically created by the operating system for each of the clients. All instances of a named pipe share the same pipe name, but each instance has its own buffers and handles, and provides a separate conduit for client/server communication. The use of instances enables multiple pipe clients to use the same named pipe simultaneously. Any process can act as both a server for one pipe and a client for another pipe, and vice versa, making peer-to-peer communication possible.

If you will use a named pipe, there would be no need in the events at all in your scenario, and the data will have guaranteed delivery no matter what happens with the processes – each of the processes may get long delays (e.g. by a swap) but the data will be finally delivered ASAP without your special involvement.

One event for all threads (processes) is only OK if the notification will be only once. In this case, you will need the manual-reset event, not an auto-reset one. For example, if you need to notify that your application will very soon exit, you may signal this common manual-reset event. But, as I wrote before, in your scenario, named pipes is the best choice.